# iOS Swift: tableview controller flow order

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am new to Swift and trying to understand table view.

I have a simple `UITableViewController` class, with two elements.

```
class NamVcc: UITableViewController
{
    var NamAryVar = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("viewDidLoad")

        NamAryVar = ["TrlTxtTooTwtAid","TrlTxtTooTwtBid"]
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        print("viewWillAppear")
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        print("viewDidAppear")
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    {
        print("viewWillLayoutSubviews")
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    {
        print("viewDidLayoutSubviews")
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool)
    {
        print("viewWillDisappear")
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool)
    {
        print("viewDidDisappear")
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
                            cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        print("cellForRowAtIndexPath")
        let TblCelVar = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TblCelUid", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        TblCelVar.textLabel?.text = NamAryVar[indexPath.row]

        return TblCelVar
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
                            numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        print("numberOfRowsInSection")
        return NamAryVar.count
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        print("numberOfSectionsInTableView")
        return 1
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I get following output:

```
viewDidLoad
viewWillAppear
numberOfSectionsInTableView
numberOfRowsInSection
numberOfSectionsInTableView
numberOfRowsInSection
viewWillLayoutSubviews
numberOfSectionsInTableView
numberOfRowsInSection
cellForRowAtIndexPath
cellForRowAtIndexPath
viewDidLayoutSubviews
viewWillLayoutSubviews
viewDidLayoutSubviews
viewDidAppear
```

I am not able to understand why `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection` are getting called three times.

what is actual flow of tableviewcontroller?

Comment: Your output already tells you the "actual flow" of the table view. It calls the data source and delegate methods whenever it needs to know such information. The order and number of calls should (mostly) be irrelevant.

Comment: Everytime i call its the same, it calls three times.

My question is only to understand why 3 times and how can u tell irrelevant ?

Comment: It might call them dozens of times. It depends on how many sections you have and how many rows are in each section. It all depends on how `UITableView` is implemented. Again, it doesn't matter how many times they are called. But if you want to know, put a break point in those methods and look at the stack trace showing when it's being called.

Comment: It is all-right, its background process and we don't need to worry.

Comment: yes we need to worry! I am unable to fetch data for second table in a view controller. And the flow checks 3 times numberOfRowsInSection instead of going in cellForRow